# Height auto - displaying hidden content when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the site im working on, forgive me if im not being specific enough, im new to this.

http://daniel.grocock.me/portnew

Setting the paragraph height for the #introexpand div and have a resize function that 
checks to see the if the #introexpand needs to fit in a bigger or smaller area when the browser has resized.

```
function resize() {
    $("#introexpand").css("height", "auto").show();
    var pHeight = $("#introexpand p:first").height() + 15;
    $("#introexpand").css("height", pHeight);
}
```

So im setting the pHeight to auto before resetting height and to show it for a brief second so the correct height can be obtained.

The problem is now when i resize the browser the #introexpand div pops down before the link span.learnmore is clicked.

If i remove height auto from the CSS it seems to fix it but then the #introexpand div dosent function when clicked.

Comment: Is this function is running inside of `$(window).resize()`?

Comment: @KevinB yes and its called on $.(document.ready)

Comment: Thanks @Wes its the only way im gonna learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could let this function run in a onresize-handler ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize)), but it's simpler be solved with CSS:

```css
#introexpand {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: i tried adjusting the CSS but no joy - or am i missing something else to go with it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not approach this differently. Rather than trying to calculate the height that `#introexpand` needs to be, let it always be auto and just toggle `display:none;` when you click on `span.learnmore`.

To do that, you'll need to remove `position:relative` from `#introexpand` and `position:absolute` from `#introexpand p`.

After you've done that, just default `#introexpand` to `display:none` and then on `click` on `span.learnmore` you can either `.show()` the `div` or [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) it for something a little fancier.

I just think you're trying to make it more complex than it needs to be.